# Scattering solutions for $L_2$ potentials

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schrodinger-operators

Consider the equation
$$
   Lu = -\Delta u+v(x)u = Eu, \tag{1}
$$
where $x = (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb R^2$, $v \in L_2(\mathbb R^2)$, $E>0$. Is it known that for almost any $E>0$ and for any fixed $k \in \mathbb R^2$ with $k_1^2+k_2^2 = E$ there exists a solution of (1) with asymptotics
$$
   u(x,k) = e^{ikx}+A\biggl(k,|k|\frac{x}{|x|}\biggr) \frac{e^{i|k||x|}}{\sqrt{|x|}} + o(|x|^{-\frac 1 2}), \quad |x| \to \infty \quad ?
$$
For sufficiently smooth and rapidly decaying potentials $v$ it is true but in my question $v$ is an arbitrary $L_2$-potential. For the case of smooth and rapidly decaying potentials the following formula holds:
$$
  A(k,l) = C \int\limits_{\mathbb R^2} e^{i(k-l)x} u(x,k)v(x) \, dx.
$$
If the answer to my first question is positive is it possible to say that in the $L_2$-case the analogical formula holds where we only need to add $p.v.$ before the integral sign?